# Reactjs : Getting a input value from many inputs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Im trying to get some input value from a library(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-auth-code-input)
, but im getting an error
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')

code :

```
  {...}
const Login = ({loginUser}) =>{
  const history = useHistory();
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = useState(false);
  const [Token,setToken] =useState(0);


  return (
    <div>
      <StyledFormArea>
        <TextLink to="/home">
           {...}
 <AuthCode
                          characters={6}
                          onChange= {e => setToken(e.target.value)}
                          containerClassName="Input"
                          inputClassName="input"
                        />
{...}
```

someone knows an function that gets more than one input value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onChange` method from the library definition tells you that the return value is the a string (assuming it’s the input string value), no the event. So instead of `e.target.value` it would just be `e` (I would rename this :) )

For reference here is the definition of the `onChange` method implementation from the library (found [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-auth-code-input))

```
Callback function called every time an input value changes
```

So the `onChange` Will give you the text value of the input.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @ndvictor14 Like this ? `onChange= {e => setToken(e)}`       then it will be stored in my state TOken ?